# Xamarin ImageResource extension doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to validate user input form using Xamarin behavior and converter. Trying to convert boolean to object to show right and wrong images using `ImageResource` extension but images are not showing up.

Here is my XAML markup:

```
<converter:BooleanToObjectConverter x:Key="boolToStyleImage"
                                              x:TypeArguments="Style">
        <converter:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
          <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{extension:ImageResource Uno.Images.error.png}" />
          </Style>
        </converter:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>

        <converter:BooleanToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
          <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{extension:ImageResource Uno.Images.success.png}" />
          </Style>
        </converter:BooleanToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
      </converter:BooleanToObjectConverter>
```

and my boolean to object converter code:

```
public class BooleanToObjectConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
        public T FalseObject { set; get; }
        public T TrueObject { set; get; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? this.TrueObject : this.FalseObject;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((T)value).Equals(this.TrueObject);
        }
}
```

and my image resource extension class:

```
[ContentProperty("Source")]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
                return null;

            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);
            return imageSource;
        }
}
```

Can anybody help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Charles Petzolds book:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/

Page 874 in the triggers and behaviours chapter should point you in the right direction.

Your ImageResourceExtension and BoolToObject converter are correct.

Make sure the images you're trying to use have a build action of Embedded Resource

Comment: How to make those images to have build action of Embedded Resource? I am new to Xamarin so I don't know how to do it on vs2015. I have right clicked on those images but can't see build action option from the context menu.

Comment: It's under the properties section. Right click on the image, select Properties. The build action will be in the advanced section of that window.

Answer (score 0):

**In model make that**

```
    public class NodeItem
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public ImageSource MyImageSource
    {
        get
        { //here you decide what resource to use
            return ImageSource.FromResource(ImagePath);
        }
    }
}
```

**In ViewModel**

```
RoladyItems.Add(new NodeItem() { ImagePath = "Project.Images.Rolady._MG_8150_521x347.png", Name = "Rolada 1", Price = 9.99 });
```